# Kernel 5.14 causes freezing on one computer, but not another?

Tags: nvidia, kernel

I have a PC and laptop, both running vanilla Ubuntu 20.04. I've just upgraded both to kernel 5.14 (I need the USB latency enhancements). Laptop is working fine, but PC gets ridiculously slow already when loading the login screen. Everything takes like 100 times longer to load, even stuff like resizing a window takes like 2 minutes, so it's basically unusable.

PC: Intel Core I9-9900K, Nvidia RTX 2070 Super 8 GB, 64 GB RAM

Laptop: Intel Xeon W-10885M, Nvidia Quadro RTX 3000 6 GB, 64 GB RAM

Both are running identical latest Nvidia driver 470.74. I have even tried to reinstall the PC, but that didn't help.

Any ideas, at least thoughts on probable causes appreciated.

Comment: Kernel 5.14 is not supported on ubuntu 20.04 and may break your system, So I suggest to download kernel 5.4 instead of 5.14 or else you may end up destroying your system.

Comment: BTW, I like your PC specs, It looks like it was Mac before you downloaded linux so probably kernel 5.14 will work.